# Visual Studio not recognizing javascript function because of Html.Action

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I put an @Url.Action inside a javascript function, Visual Studio will not recognize that function. There will be not collapse/expand option.

```
     function exeAjax(id, destination) {

        $("#contents").show();
        destination.html("loading...");

        $.ajax({
          cache: false,
          type: "GET",
          url: '@Url.Action("MyAction")',
          data: { "id": id },
          success: function (data) {

            destination.html(data);

          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert('failed');
          }
        });
      }
```

The line will be recognizable if I change from:

```
url: '@Url.Action("MyAction")'
```

To:

```
url: 'MyAction'
```

**Edit:**

There's no error and the code runs exactly as expected.

It's just the function region is not recognized by the IDE.

Comment: Take a look at this, it might help some: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_posting_to.ashx

Comment: What do you mean *recognize*? Do you get an error? Is this script inside a view or an external JS file?

Comment: No, there's no error and the code runs exactly as expected.
It's just the function region is not recognized by the IDE.

Comment: This is happening in VS2012 as well.  VS2010 does not have this problem! Very annoying!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should not add any Razor code in Javascript/ Jquery. Because you will ideally like to have all the Javascript/ Jquery in a .js file, and @ will try to invoke a razor code. for your issue you can do

$.ajax({
          cache: false,
          type: "GET",
          url: '../MyAction', // path to your action
          data: { "id": id },
          success: function (data) {

```
        destination.html(data);

      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('failed');
      }
    });
```

Hope it works, happy coding

Comment: But if you have a partial view that's being used in multiple pages and each one has it's own Action to call...

Comment: That is a interesting, and it can be solved in many ways.. one being where you pass in a value as a constructor to your js function.. with the path.. or you can use the data-* notation to store the path or any other design which may suit your app.. if you lay some specifics would love to share any inputs

Comment: Yes, there's those workarounds but I was looking just for some kind of escape char.
Because the code works perfectly like this, it's just an IDE thing...